# How to order the result from distinct list in MongoDB via Java Driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using MongoDB via Java Driver (Spring Data MongoDB). Now my code is like:

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("user", user);    
mongoTemplate.getCollection("reports").distinct("category", query);
```

Right now, the result list is not ordered. I want to it sorting by a ASC order. I have check this question [Query MongoDB for ordered distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475361/query-mongodb-for-ordered-distinct-values) but I only get the answer which order the list by java side. How to order the result in MongoDB side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use the [Distinct command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/#dbcmd.distinct) with a "sort" parameter with standard queries.

However, you can use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) to do these more complex queries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I need to learn aggregation framework.