# Get sorted distinct values with MongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I am trying to get list of sorted distinct fields:

```
public List<Object> getDistinctValues(String collection, String fieldName) {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, fieldName));
    return mongoTemplate.findDistinct(query, fieldName, collection, Object.class);
}
```

but sorting isn't applied.
Is there any way to do it with mongoTemplate?

spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb: **2.1.2.RELEASE**

Comment: Have a look at this. > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476675/how-to-order-the-result-from-distinct-list-in-mongodb-via-java-driver

Comment: @AlaguMS Yes, I saw. There is no helpful answer for me.

Comment: well you can still sort the document in java after retrieving it if you dont want to use aggregations.

Comment: @RichieK, I don't know the typo of field.. So I can't sort values on java side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on previous answer I solved my problem with Mongo Aggregation:

```
@Override
public List<Object> getDistinctValues(String collection, String fieldName, Sort.Direction sort) {
    Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.group(fieldName),
            Aggregation.sort(sort, "_id")
    );
    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, collection, Document.class)
            .getMappedResults()
            .stream()
            .map(item -> item.get("_id"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I hope it will be helpful for somebody.

Comment: Get does not work form me (.map(item -> item.get("_id")). Its not being picked up as a method at all.

Answer (score 2):

With Mongo Aggregation you can

```
db.getCollection('assignments').aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: "$fieldname"}},
    {$sort : {"_id" :1}}
    ])
```