# Improve aggregation query to get distinct results

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, projection, mongotemplate

I have this aggregation query that returns `Operation` objects with field `amount:BigDecimal` higher than `minAmount` and within a date range.I would like to get only distinct results (each `Operation` object has an `operationId:String`), based on `operationId`.

I have found a relevant example here, but it has not help me get through my issue: [Get sorted distinct values with MongoTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54791594/get-sorted-distinct-values-with-mongotemplate)

I understand that `addToSet`, or `group` can be used, but I am unclear on how exactly to incorporate it within the rest of the query

```
    private List<OperationDataVO> getInfoFromDB(BigDecimal minAmount,
                                                     Instant startDate, Instant endDate) {
        Criteria criterias = new Criteria()
            .andOperator(Criteria.where(WinningOperation.AMOUNT)
                    .gte(minAmount)
                    .and(Operation.TYPE).is(OperationTypeEnum.WINNING_TYPE)
                    .and("createdAt").gte(startDate).lte(endDate));

        MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(criterias);

        ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = 
                Aggregation.project("amount", "operationId");

        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperation,
                projectionOperation, sort(direction, "amount"));

        AggregationResults<OperationDataVO> aggregate = mongoTemplate
                .aggregate(aggregation, COLLECTION, OperationDataVO.class);

        return aggregate.getMappedResults();
    }
```

Also, I have tried adding a group operation in the `Aggregation` pipeline, but when I do so, I get a list of `OperationDataVO`where both fields of every object are `null`

(`Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperation, projectionOperation, sort(direction, "amount"), group("operationId"));` )

Comment: if there are multiple documents with the same `operationId` which one do you want to return?

Comment: The one with the highest "amount:BigDecimal" value

Comment: So, you want to group them by `operationId`, sort each group descending by `amount`, then get the first of each group.

Comment: I recommend creating the appropriate query in mongodb shell (or equivalent tool) first and then translating that to Spring Data Mongo.

Comment: What do you need in the resulting `OperationDataVO`?  Only `amount` and `operationId` ?  And everything sorted ascending by `amount`?

Comment: Yes, I only need to have these two fields inside OperationDataVO

Comment: And everything sorted by amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort descending by `amount` before doing the grouping.
Grouping should be done using the '$first' accumulator.  We retain the whole document using `$$ROOT`.
You can then replace the root document with the document from the group.

Grouping doesn't preserve any order, since you want to have the end result sorted you need to sort again.

The mongo shell code to achieve this will look like this:

```
db.getCollection('operationData').aggregate([
{ $match: ... } ,
{ $project: { amount: 1, operationId: 1 } },
{ $sort: { amount: -1 } },
{ $group: { _id: '$operationId', g: { $first: {data: '$$ROOT'} }} },
{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$g.data' }},
{ $sort: { amount: 1 } }
])
```

This will need to be translated to Spring Data Mongo (maybe I'll have time later to try this myself).

Comment: Thank you. Using this query in "Studio 3T for MongoDB" though, returns only the OperationDataVO, derived by the Operation object with the highest "amount" value

Comment: It was the $ missing from the "operationId" in group

Comment: Indeed I just adapted it.

Comment: Does "g" stand for something specific?

Comment: @MilanPopescu I chose it as abbreviation for "group" but it's just the name for a field that won't end up in the final document, so you can choose anything (but adapt both lines where it's used of course).